# Using sed in a Jython script to replace a whole line with a variable in a text file

Tags: python, bash, sed, jython, os.system

In a Jython script I am trying to replace an entire line of a text file (the 2nd line in this case) with a directory address that contains a variable (VAR).

```
obsids=str(obsids[i])
print type(obsids)
os.system('sed -i "2 s:.*:/usr/data/$obsids/:" /usr/software/file.txt')
```

Where `obsids` was a unicode of a whole number, then a string (usually something like 1342204440).

Please can you show me the error in my script.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to use the variable and not the text `$VAR`, then you need to double quote the `sed` command.

Comment: Your Python snippet is completely broken, and the error message is unreadable too.

Comment: @fedorqui thanks, I don't get the error message now and the script runs, but it doesn't execute the sed command as desired

Comment: @ErikAllik what do you mean? It seems that fedorqui and myself can see it :/

Comment: @ThatWilsoKid Please update your question showing the exact code your are using, as well as the value of `$VAR` (maybe it contains a `/` so it conflicts with the sed delimiter)

Comment: @fedorqui Updated, I thought it could be an issue with the variable being a unicode not a string, but that doesn't seem to alter it not working

Comment: Mmmm first of all, what `sed` replacement you want to do? I guess you want to replace everything up to `:` with `/usr/data/$obsids/:`. Note that you need `"` instead of `'` to have the $obsids variable expanded.

Comment: @fedorqui I would like to replace everything on the 2nd line in file.txt with `/usr/data/$obsids/`

Comment: @ThatWilsoKid so `sed "2 s:.*:/usr/data/$obsids/:" your_file` should make it.

Comment: @fedorqui updated to your sugestion, it now replaces the correct line in the text file, but without the `obsids`, does it matter what type `obsids` is?

Comment: But what do you want? `$obsids` to be this exact value or to use the value of `obsids` variable?

Comment: @fedorqui the value of the `obsids` variable

Comment: @ThatWilsoKid I guess the variable is not set properly. Does it work to you if you do `os.system('obsid="testvalue"; sed "2 s:.*:/usr/data/$obsids/:" /usr/software/file.txt')`?

Comment: @fedorqui you are correct, it returns as /usr/data/testvalue/ so how do I set the variable properly?

Comment: @ThatWilsoKid I think it is a matter of using `os.environ['obsids']=obsids`. I just posted it as an answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got it in the comments:

```
obsids=str(obsids[i])
print type(obsids)
os.environ['obsids']=obsids  # this makes the Python variable behave inside UNIX
os.system('sed -i "2 s:.*:/usr/data/$obsids/:" /usr/software/file.txt')
```

Comment: It works. Sir you are a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you for your help!

Comment: We made it :) It was a nice exercise of virtual debugging, well done!